# User input and automated input separation

Tags: programming-practices, database-design, methodology, automation

I have a MySQL database and an automation script which modifies the data inside once a day. And these columns may have changed by an user manually. What is the best approach to make the system only update the automated data, not the manually edited ones? I mean yes, flagging the cell which is manually edited is one way to do it, but I want to know if there's another way to accomplish this? Just curiosity.

BTW, the question is about cell values, not rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put two DateTime columns in those tables, one called `lastUserEdit` and the other one called `lastAutomatedEdit`.  That way, you always know whether the last edit on each row was done by a user or automatically by simply comparing these two dates.

Comment: but it's not any different from flagging. just using date1>date2 as the boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Flagging as you have mentioned is what I'd do.
Just by updating the value in an `ENUM column ('0','1')` to let you know who last updated the record.

Comment: Yes but I'm looking for different approaches. Like when it's a string, I would prepend a "user:" to it, when it's a date I would add 20 years to it if its user edited etc. And BTW the question is about cells. not rows.